# `accepts_nested_attributes_for` attributes not getting cloned

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a new instance of a model, however I want to bring some parameters from a different record also, essentially duplication most of the parameters into the new instance but leaving some fields blank as well.

Cloning it works (thanks [@weppos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/weppos))

```
# class RecipesController
def new
  @parent = Recipe.find(params[:parent_id])
  @recipe = @parent.clone
end
```

And while this does work, it breaks all my nested attributes:

```
# class Recipe
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.values.all?(&:blank?) }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Like it only saves the new attributes and throws all the old ones away, the ones that should have been duplicated from the other instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `clone` method.

```
@parent = Recipe.find(params[:parent_id])
@recipe = @parent.clone
```

If the clone behavior doesn't apply to your need, then you can create a custom method starting from `#clone` then unsetting all unnecessary properties.

Comment: hmmm... clone worked perfectly, however it didn’t clone any of my nested attributes. Is it related to this bug > https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3391-nested-attributes-vs-before_save